# Java library import difficulty

Tags: java, linux

I'm trying to compile a small test program I have written for a raspberry pi.
The program makes use of the Pi4J library to control the piface add-on board.

What I have done so far is based on the following tutorial: http://www.savagehomeautomation.com/piface

While I can get the above example program to compile within my IDE after setting up the class paths I get compile errors with the one I have made and as far as I can tell the imports are set up in the same way.

It says that each of the following packages does not exist:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import com.pi4j.component.switches.SwitchListener;
import com.pi4j.component.switches.SwitchState;
import com.pi4j.component.switches.SwitchStateChangeEvent;
import com.pi4j.device.piface.PiFace;
import com.pi4j.device.piface.PiFaceLed;
import com.pi4j.device.piface.PiFaceRelay;
import com.pi4j.device.piface.PiFaceSwitch;
import com.pi4j.device.piface.impl.PiFaceDevice;
import com.pi4j.wiringpi.Spi;
```

I'm assuming that my problem is relatively simple but I don't really understand how import statements work and it's quite vague topic to search about. I have included some file paths if that helps.

This is where my project resides:

```
/home/pi/JBerries/relay
```

and this is where the pi4j library is:

```
/opt/pi4j
```

I hope the following image provides some of the information requested, note that the class paths are already set up:
[image: jBerries IDE screenshot]

Comment: What are the compile errors you get?

Comment: which IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using jBerries (someone released it the other day on the raspberry pi forums) - see the screenshot for compile errors.
Also displayed is the preferences where the class paths are set to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the CLASSPATH environment variable to /opt/pi4j or the jar file therein. WIthout this the compiler is unable to know where your libary is located and will give you the errors you describe.

Comment: The class paths are already set up within the IDE, see the screenshot I posted above. Not sure if this is what you meant.

Comment: Can you try compiling this on the command line? I'm not familiar with JBerries but it seems the classpath is set correctly.

Comment: I've set up the whole thing from scratch again, looks like it could have been something spelt wrong or with the wrong name... Just got some different errors to deal with now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a project in JBerries you need to configure the classpath for the project - the screenshot shows the classpath for single-file compilations only. To edit the project config right-click the root node in the project window and select properties.